# Decide upon method usage at runtime. Polymorphism

Tags: java, design-patterns, polymorphism

Well, this is kind of embarrassing, but I've forgotten how to do the following in plain old Java:

```
abstract class Animal {
   protected String name;
   public Animal(String name) {
       this.name = name;
   }
}

class Flea extends Animal {
    private double jumpHeight;

    public Flea(String name, double jumpHeight) {
        super(name);
        this.jumpHeight = jumpHeight;
    }

    public double jump() {
       return jumpHeight();
    }
}

class Giraffe extends Animal {
    private int strideLength;

    public Giraffe(int strideLength) {
        super("Berta");
        this.strideLength = strideLength;
    }

    public int stride() { return strideLength; }
}

class Gorilla extends Animal {
    private String call;

    public Gorilla(String call) {
        super("Boris");
        this.call = call;
    }

    public String call() { return "Gorilla says " + call; }
}
```

Now I would like to decide the appropriate method at runtime, without having to add all the methods to each Animal (no abstract methods) and without meaningless placeholders (like imagine a Flea has no call).

I would like to do this **without** casting. So ***no***:

```
if(Animal instanceof Gorilla) ((Gorilla) animal).call();
```

I could come up with a solution incorporating interfaces like `jumpable` and could use that, but I'm sure there was a certain pattern that was exactly for this kind of task.

Any ideas?

Comment: Given a reference to the base class, if there's no common interface then you're going to have to do some casting *somewhere* (unless you want to get crazy and invoke the method via reflection). What is the real problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: just implement all needed methods in `Animal` and overwrite the needed ones in your subclasses

Comment: Check the visitor pattern.

Comment: this is not polymorphism, a flee and a gorilla need to have common behaviour. For example, call it *behave()* and then a Flee can jump, and Gorilla can call etc...

Comment: @dnault Its not true, see my answer for details.

Comment: I would like to see, "_a solution incorporating interfaces like `jumpable`_".

Answer (score 2):

You should consider the [visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern#Java_example):

```
abstract class Animal {
   public abstract void acceptAnimalVisitor(AnimalVisitor visitor);
}

class Flea extends Animal {
   public void acceptAnimalVisitor(AnimalVisitor visitor){
        visitor.visit(this);
   }
} 

// other animals also implementing acceptAnimalVisitor

public class AnimalVisitor{
   public void visit(Flea flea){
      // ...
   }

   // other visit methods for the other animals
}
```

However, this requires at least one method (the accept method itself). Also note that you can convert the AnimalVisitor into an interface, and that way you can easily achieve the so called [double dispatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch).

Comment: Works with `void` but what about different return-values like in the example?

Comment: As I understood those methods in the example are basically getters that can be used in the visit method. The idea is to decouple the algorithm from the object, so the return value does not really matter. If this is not what you are looking for, then this pattern is not for you:)

Comment: Nah, I see, I would need to implement multiple visitors or methods for each animal being visited :)

Comment: Allright, then I think I don't understand what you try to accomplish. You should further clarify the question.